# Tracking and logging entities with timestamp and namestamping in Simulink SIMEVENTS

Tags: matlab, simulink, discrete-mathematics, timestamping, simevents

I am working on a project involving discrete event system in production engineering. I am new to Simevents (used to simulate discrete event systems) in SIMULINK.

The entities generate block generates entities for the system. For my project, it is required to record the data such as Entity unique number, time within the system.

Is there any particular method to access the values generated in Block  Paramters?

Regards,
Arun Kumar

Answer (score 0):

[MATLAB has a series of 7 videos to introduce the concepts and tools required to answer the questions.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mrh19DXLa5s&list=PLn8PRpmsu08q99DkBGxwmd5KxzZZBpm4c)

Entity data is referred to as 'attributes'.  Accessing and setting user-defined attributes are performed with block functions as shown in videos 4 & 5.

Video 2 shows how to visualize the arrival-time of entities.